# Call a service from a different component to display a message

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, angular2-services

I have a shared component alert which displays different alerts (error, success..) that uses a service 'alertService'.

I have different components that uses the 'alertService'.

The alert component is called in the appComponent like so:
`<app-alert></app-alert>`

When I call the service from another component the alert isn't displayed, it displays only when I call `<app-alert></app-alert>` in the component that call the service.

Comment: Can you please provide us with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see what it is that you've actually done. Maybe then we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution: I provide the alert service in the app.module
It was provided in the shared.module.